# summary matrix by ID combination by r

Tags: r, matrix

I have a df (test) like this

[image]

Now if you look at the data, 6 to 10 combination is available in the second period but not in the first period. Hence when I use this code

```
a_summary <- test %>%
  group_by(from, to) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(share, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(from, avg, fill = 0)
```

The output comes like this
[image]

Now, look at the 10 to 6 cell. it gives a value of 1 because 10 to 6 combination only exist one time. But when I make the average, I would like to consider all combination in each period. hence the expected outcome of that 10 to 6 cell is .5 and overall matrix column and row summation should be 1.

Comment: I have edit it sorry

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. In this case, use something like `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative sample of your data, using something like `head`, `sample`, or manual row-picking.

Answer (score 0):

```
a_summary <- test %>%
group_by(from, to) %>%
summarize(count = sum(n, na.rm = T)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
spread(from, count, fill = 0)
```

This will give you all count of all combinations. Now you can normalize this matrix with dividing by `sum(test$n)` or use `prop.table()`

Comment: The row and col sum still more than one

Comment: it makes bigger probabilities. Sorry